# Catch all events for children using dataset

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I have a wrapper (DIV) with children and a event listener on the wrapper. I would like to process keyboard and click events by *dataset* value on the wrapper.

As in catch all events for children in wrapper.

Simple example:

```js
let wrap = document.getElementById("wrap");
let status = document.getElementById("status");
let keyact = {
    a: function(e) {
        status.textContent = "Do A " + e.key;
    },
    b: function(e) {
        status.textContent = "Do B " + e.key;
    },
};

function keycheck(e) {
    let t = e.target,
        d = t.dataset;
    status.textContent = "X trap";
    if (d.keyact && keyact[d.keyact])
        keyact[d.keyact](e);
    else
        status.textContent = "No trap";
}
function tabtrap(e) {
    if (e.target.className == "tab_trap")
        wrap.focus();
}
document.addEventListener('keydown', keycheck);
document.addEventListener('keyup', tabtrap);
status.textContent = "ready";
```

```css
div, a {
  border  : 1px solid #eee;
  margin: 2px;
}
*:focus {
  border  : 1px solid red;
  outline : 0;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex=0 class="tab_trap"></div>
<div id="wrap" data-keyact="a" tabindex=0>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Dummy 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dummy 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dummy 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div tabindex=0 class="tab_trap"></div>
<p id="status"></p>
```

If the user presses a key while the `#wrap` DIV has focus, the `keyact` function is processed (as it has a *dataset*-act value of `a`).

I would like `keyact.a()` to be executed when a key is pressed while focus on any child element of the DIV wrapper. For example *"Dummy 1"*, ***Without*** setting the dataset value for each and every child element.

If the value of `data-keytrap` is changed to `b` I would like `b` to be executed etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to invoke a function in `keyact` based on a the corresponding DOM attribute presenting in `#wrap`. There are many ways this can be achieved, however the following should meet your requirements (see comments in snippet for more detail):

```js
let status = document.getElementById("status");
let keyact = {
    a: function(e) {
        status.textContent = "Do A " + e.key;
    },
    b: function(e) {
        status.textContent = "Do B " + e.key;
    },
};

// Query all nodes in document with data-keyact attribute
document.body.querySelectorAll('[data-keyact]').forEach(element => {

  // For this data-keyact node add keydown event handler
  element.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  
    // When keydown event happens, access the "keyact" attribute value from #wrap
    const actionKey = element.dataset.keyact;
    
    // Access the keyact function by the aquired actionkey
    const actionFunction = keyact[actionKey];

    // Saftey check - make sure actionFunction is a function before attempting to call
    // it
    if(typeof actionFunction === 'function') {
    
      // Pass the keydown event to actionFunction
      actionFunction(event);
    }
    
    // This is important, we don't want the keydown behaviour to propagate
    // up to parent nodes with same attribute
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
  
  // For this #wrap decendant, add keyup event handler
  element.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
    
    // When keyup happens, refocus the element
    element.focus();
    
    // This is important, we don't want the keyup focus behavior to propagate
    // up to parent nodes with same attribute
    event.stopPropagation();
  });

});
```

```css
div, a {
  border  : 1px solid #eee;
  margin: 2px;
}
*:focus {
  border  : 1px solid red;
  outline : 0;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex=0 class="tab_trap"></div>
<div id="wrap" data-keyact="a" tabindex=0> (keyact a)
  <ul>
    <li><a data-keyact="b" href="#">Dummy 1 (keyact b)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dummy 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dummy 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div tabindex=0 class="tab_trap"></div>
<p id="status"></p>
```

Comment: Hi @user3342816 , you're welcome :) so just to make sure I'm understanding you correctly, you'd like a solution that handles the keyboard events for both #wrap and the descendants of #wrap?